# Reference request for quadratic form diagonalization

Tags: reference-request, quadratic-forms

I want to read a proof of "Every quadratic form q in n variables over a field of characteristic not equal to 2 is equivalent to a diagonal form" using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. Could anyone suggets a reference to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty confident that Jacobson's [*Basic Algebra I*](http://books.google.com/books?id=JHFpv0tKiBAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=jacobson+basic+algebra+I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mwydUJv3EYX68gTFm4CIBQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) covers reducing quadratic forms to diagonal form in chapter 6 *Metric vector spaces and the classical groups*.

I think I remember another proof, in less generality, in [*Tensor analysis on manifolds*](http://books.google.com/books?id=LAuN5-og4jwC&pg=PA59&dq=goldberg+vector+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PAydULmAAofc9ATpvoGICA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false). I remember it was very readable and definitely used Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Thank you @rschwieb. I confirmed that both of two proofs you mentioned are indeed based on Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Aki Happy to help!